# Design Pattern for class bookings

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am designing a small application to manage class sign-ups and appointment bookings within a school.

I will have students who will want to book classes, Teachers who teach classes in the room and also have an office room and guests will book in meetings with teachers in one of their rooms.

I will also need to print out a report of all meetings and classes and which rooms and who attended.

Which design patterns would be best?

I have been looking at possibly the Factory/ iterator and composite so far but not sure which would be most suitable or what the potential issues that might arise?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you have rooms, time slots, and you have to assign them to resources. This is a typical Constraint Satisfaction Problem (CSP). There are many ways to solve such kind of problems. One is backtracking algorithm. There is another approach called Genetic Algorithm that helps you pick up the best solutions. Please search those.

Thanks.